# Problem editing/filling out form for newly created profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, routes

I'm almost finished with a sign-up process where:

- (Step 1) New User completes a small form, creating both a User and Profile
- (Step 2) New User is redirected to ProfilesController to fill in the rest of the profile
- (Step 3) New User completes Profile, and is redirected to their Profile

Yet something isn't working right. I believe what I've done is made it so that a Profile is created in both steps 1 and 2 of the above. (Sort of like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350364/edit-method-is-creating-new-records-instead-of-just-updating-existing-ones), but my methods are different.)

Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is my code.

**ProfilesController:**

```
def new
  @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @user.profile
  @superlative = @profile.superlatives.new
end

def edit
  @profile = user.profile
end
```

**UsersController:**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.profile = Profile.new
  if logged_in?
    redirect_to current_user.profile
  end
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to signup_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @user = current_user
end

def update
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:email])
    redirect_to profile_path
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb:**

```
match "/signup" => "profiles#edit", :as => "signup"
post "/profiles/new" => "profiles#create"
match "skip/signup", :to => "info#signupskip"
match "skip/profiles/new", :to => "profiles#newskip"
get "/profiles/:id" => "profiles#show", :as => "profile"
get "profiles/new"
root :to => "users#new"
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

Form #1 (Users#new form):

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => 'homesign'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :size => 38 %>
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
  <div id="name">
    <%= profile.label :first_name %>
    <%= profile.text_field :first_name, :size => 18 %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Form #2 (Profiles#new) form:

```
<%= form_for '@user.profile', :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
    <table id="signupTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="label"><%= f.label :gender, "Gender:" %></td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

If I use the above, I get "Couldn't find User with ID=xx"

If I change the above route from:

```
match "/signup" => "profiles#new", :as => "signup"
```

To:

```
match "/signup" => "profiles#edit", :as => "signup"
```

I get "Couldn't find User without an ID"

**From `rake routes`:**

```
profiles_show GET    /profiles/show(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
profiles_new GET    /profiles/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
POST   /profiles/new(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}

user_profiles GET    /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profiles"}
POST   /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
PUT    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
DELETE /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"profiles"}
users GET    /users(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
POST   /users(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

I also have the following routes for signup:

```
signup_index GET    /signup(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"signup"}
POST   /signup(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"signup"}
new_signup GET    /signup/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"signup"}
edit_signup GET    /signup/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"signup"}
GET    /signup/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"signup"}
PUT    /signup/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"signup"}
DELETE /signup/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"signup"}
```

**UPDATE: `rake routes` with just `resources: users`, `resources :profiles`, and root.**

```
users GET    /users(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
POST   /users(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profiles"}
POST   /profiles(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"profiles"}
root        /(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using accepts_nested_attributes_for in your user model? At the very least, it might clean up your code. But, anyway, I believe the problem is with your routes. In addition to reading through this code, I suggest you run a "rake routes" in your application root to make sure that the routes you're trying to use actually exist.

**Update:** For your particular codebase, here's what you need to do.

**Use these routes in your routes.rb:**

```
resources :profiles
resources :users
root :to => "users#new"
```

**You also need to change:**

`redirect_to profile_path` to `redirect_to @user.profile`

`redirect_to signup_path ...` to `redirect_to edit_profile_path(@user.profile)`

**Here is what I usually do with users and profiles, might help:**

**Scaffolds (just for context):**

```
rails generate scaffold User username:string password:string
rails generate scaffold Profile user_id:integer email_address:string website:string
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :profiles
resources :users
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @profile = Profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile.nil? ? Profile.new : @user.profile

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    if params[:user][:profile]
      profile = params[:venue][:profile]
      params[:user].delete(:profile)
      params[:user].update({ :profile_attributes => profile })
    end

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to :action => (@user.profile.nil? ? @user : @user.profile) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  def update
    if params[:user][:profile]
      profile = params[:venue][:profile]
      params[:user].delete(:profile)
      params[:user].update({ :profile_attributes => profile })
    end

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to :action => (@user.profile.nil? ? @user : @user.profile) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

**models/profile.rb:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**models/user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

**users/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  ...

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for @profile, :profile do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :email_address %><br />
      <%= ff.text_field :email_address %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Using this kind of process flow, somebody can create a user and a profile, and the only form values for profile which will be filled in are ones that you specify defaults for or those that appear in the fields_for block. I think that what you were trying to do isn't overly complicated, but I think you may have been approaching in the wrong way with regards to your routing.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for in my Models. I have two forms, one that is a nested model form (creates user and profile), the other solely for the profile. The route issue has to occur in between when the User and Profile are created in the first form, then are redirected to fill in/edit the profile that was just created.

Comment: I'm a beginner to programming but clearly I need to refresh my understanding of routes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include information from `rake routes`? You only need to include the lines for profile and user.

Comment: I've put all the routes in. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: See the updates I posted, particularly about the redirect_to and routes changes. Use only those routes, and make the redirect_to changes, and let us know how it goes and any questions you might have.

Comment: I'm assuming this also requires my changing how I structure my nested model form and the other form? Specifically using `form_for @user.profile` (Profile) and `@user` to create User and Profile.

Comment: Shouldn't change anything in your form. It doesn't look like you were making use of the nested routes anyway, but your form should work fine for nested attributes. However, I did miss one thing in your form. You need to remove '@user.profile' from quotes.

Comment: Thanks! So after creating enough Users so that the # of Users was the same # of Profiles (it messed up if a new User had id=97 with a new Profile with id=109 for example) the redirect is to `Profiles#edit` which is great. However `edit` is something I want to be part of settings. What I want instead of `Profiles#edit` is a form where the user can fill in the rest of the profile that's just been created. I had wanted that URL to be /signup but I guess all my routes was messing this up.