# Edit inserting new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails 4 Application where I have the following code:

my _form_html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @store, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <% if params[:action] == "new" %>
      <textarea name="store[products_attributes][0][product_fields_attributes][0][text_content]"></textarea>
   <% else %>
      <textarea name="store[products_attributes][0][product_fields_attributes][0][text_content]">VALUE</textarea>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

My controller looks like:

```
before_action :set_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
  @store = Store.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  @store = Store.new(store_params)
  respond_to do |format|
     if @store.save
        format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully created.'}
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @store }
     else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
  end
end

def update
   respond_to do |format|
      if @store.update(store_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end

def set_store
  @store = Store.find(params[:id])
end

def store_params
  params.require(:store).permit(:name, products_attributes: [:id, { product_fields_attributes: [:id, :text_content] } ])
end
```

Also my edit.html.erb looks like:

```
<h3>Edit</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and my new.html.erb looks like:

```
<h3>Add New</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and in my rails console when I click "Update" looks like:

```
Started PATCH "/stores/sNx92thyjcP_jw" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 17:10:46 -0600
Processing by StoresController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nFUg4ynXYyg99rPPPoa3uO/iHP4LT1XlOz3Vm3Zm4Z0=", "store"=>{"name"=>"Testing", "description"=>"", "products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"type_of"=>"Book", "product_fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"text_content"=>"testing testing testing 1"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Update Store", "token"=>"sNx92thyjcP_jw"}
Site Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."token" = 'sNx92thyjcP_jw' LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "store_id", "type_of", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 23:10:46 UTC +00:00], ["store_id", 102], ["type_of", "Book"], ["updated_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 23:10:46 UTC +00:00]]
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "product_fields" ("created_at", "text_content", "updated_at", "product_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 23:10:46 UTC +00:00], ["text_content", "testing testing testing 1"], ["updated_at", Tue, 27 May 2014 23:10:46 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 111]]
(15.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/sNx92thyjcP_jw
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 17.6ms)
```

My store model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_token

  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products

  def to_param
    token
  end

  private

  def generate_token
    self.token = loop do
    random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10, false)
    break random_token unless Store.exists?(token: random_token)
  end
end
```

My product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :store
has_many :product_fields
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_fields
end
```

My product fields model:

```
class ProductField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    mount_uploader :image_content, ImageUploader
end
```

But when you go to edit the store, instead of updating, it adds a new record. For example, on the new page, you put in the textarea "Testing 1", and then save. Then you go to the edit page and edit the textarea that says "Testing 1" to be "Testing 2", and click save. Now I have two records: "Testing 1" and "Testing 2".

What is going on here? Thanks for all help!

Comment: you need to add the controller code here.

Comment: Please share your controller code, as well as the views for `new` and `create`. Also, your `textarea`s are identical, what’s the point of the `params` check?

Comment: @BuckDoyle, I just updated the question with more code. I didn't post it, but in the textarea meant for the edit page, there is the current value inside.

Comment: In which view files you are calling that partial?

Comment: @Pavan, new.html.erb and edit.html.erb

Comment: The controller code you shared can’t be correct; where does `@store` come from in `update`?

Comment: @BuckDoyle, I should have posted that, sorry. I have a `before_action :set_site` callback where I set `@store`

Comment: You said `new.html.erb` and you added `add.html.erb`.

Comment: @Pavan, That's my bad, it should be new.html.erb. I fixed it

Comment: would you please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54563/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-23858511-edit-inserting-new-record since everything looks good, i want to ask few questions

Comment: Have you tried to use a simple `form_for @store` instead of the `nested_form_for`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, Yes, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: There is no `params[:store][:id]` in your hash, that is something to investigate. Just before the `nested_form_for`, can you output the value of the `@store` attributes and verify it has an `id` attribute? (for the edit action)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, Ok I did `<%= @store.id %>` and it came back with the store's id.

Comment: Can you add `f.hidden_field :id` just to see if the `id` is submitted in the Form? (and also check if the hidden field has the proper value)

Comment: I also added my models to the question in case it helps

Comment: @MrYoshiji, The hidden field has the proper value, but I got `Unpermitted parameters: id` when I tried to update, so I added the `:id` to my strong parameters (store_param), but I still get the same issue

Comment: If everything is as you typed (why didn't you just paste?), then your form is used to manipulated associated data, not the actual row from "stores". Maybe you should assign existing instances (from product, product_fields) to @variables and use them in you commit actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, for some reason you are using the `nested_form_for` helper, but you are not using nested fields at all, instead you write your html for the nested `textarea` manually, with a fixed id `[0]`? This is why it always creates a new nested field. When saving the store, it will check if the given ids exist, and if not (e.g. id `0` never exists), it will create a new record for it.

Using nested fields in rails is actually pretty simple, you should just write

```
<%= form_for @store, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
    <%= product.text_area :text_content %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

You are currently not using any dynamic adding (afaik), so you do not need to use the `nested_form_for`. From the exmaple, I am assuming you always want just one product?

In your controller you will have to change your `new` action to also create the initial product to make this work.

```
def new
  @store = Store.new
  @store.products.build
end
```

This will add one empty/new product, which you can then fill in.

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested attributs in the model so when editing the name you're creating a new associated model. The ID of the nested model should not be editable.

Check this documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

It's creating a new instance with new ID.

> :update_only
>
> For a one-to-one association, this option allows you to
> specify how nested attributes are to be used when an associated record
> already exists. In general, an existing record may either be updated
> with the new set of attribute values or be replaced by a wholly new
> record containing those values. By default the :update_only option is
> false and the nested attributes are used to update the existing record
> only if they include the record's :id value. Otherwise a new record
> will be instantiated and used to replace the existing one. However if
> the :update_only option is true, the nested attributes are used to
> update the record's attributes always, regardless of whether the :id
> is present. The option is ignored for collection associations.

Comment: It’s fine for the form to be the same in Rails. The form helper routes correctly based on whether the record is persisted.

Comment: Here's a similar problem and the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350364/edit-method-is-creating-new-records-instead-of-just-updating-existing-ones

Comment: @Muhambi i've edited this to consider your nested attributes. Can you show me your model?

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos, Yes, I added the models to the question

Comment: My guess is that you are doing something like (pseudo):
store.products.each do render partial.

Check this URL for more info about creating partials with nested:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that `my _form_html.erb` is actually `_form.html.erb` partial which you're calling from `new` and `edit` view.

Surely your form code is sending request to `create` action otherwise looking at your code there is no reason it will create new record. You should recheck it. Btw,  I dont see any reason to use `nested_form_for` you can also use `form_for` field.

Anyway, when you visit the `edit` action ie `/stores/12/edit` like path, it should pre-populate all field. check it, may be made mistake in defining `routes`. Or, you might be sending `ajax` request in a wrong way. Possibility exist.

One more thing, there is no reason to use `if-else` condition, since the outcome of both condition seems similar.

```
<%= nested_form_for @store, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <textarea name="store[products_attributes][0][product_fields_attributes][0][text_content]"></textarea>
   <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In my rails console, it says Started PATCH "/stores/sNx92thyjcP_jw" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-27 17:10:46 -0600", so that means it must be going to the create action?

Comment: I added my entire rails console response.

Comment: The request is going to `update` action. please include `product`, `product_field` and `store` model, it looks like you have added some callback.

Comment: Ok I just added my models

Answer (score 0):

Params are not correctly formated, they should have this format:

```
params = { member: { avatar_attributes: { id: '2', icon: 'sad' } } }
```

**I'ts important to send the id in order to allow rails to search for the associated model. You are sending the "0" as a key instead of value.**

Follow this guide to create the form:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

And the documentation about the nested params:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Also an alternative:

http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2012/09/20/decoupling-rails-forms-from-the-database/